# OpenGL Shader in SDL Platform Game?

Tags: opengl, rendering, sdl, shader, fragment-shader

I am new to SDL and just got a simple platform game with wall jumping and music to run:

http://postimg.org/image/k31mjej1h/

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to implement an OpenGL Shader into this game.  I use SDL_Surfaces rendered with an SDL_Renderer.  I an OpenGL context initialized in my SDL program, and my question is: **How do I set up OpenGL fragment shaders so that they will shade what SDL renders?**

My plan is to use a God Ray shader, like the one used here: http://xnauk-randomchaosblogarchive.blogspot.com/2012/10/2d-crepuscular-god-rays.html

Comment: Im not sure if you'd want to do something this complecated,but Chris ck this ou, you are probably going to modify the shader a bit and if you dont know already youay want to learn a little more about kodern opengl and shaders and how sdl is ompleneted (from a high level perspecrltive) http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/default/test/testshader.c

Comment: That is an excellent link!  So it looks like the SDL_Texture is bound to an OpenGL quad in DrawGLScene.  Is that how I have to draw textures if I want to us shaders?

Comment: I did it!  Here is a video: https://vimeo.com/161093497

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it like it was a pure OpenGL application but you need to add the SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL flag when creating the window so you application will use OpenGL not DirectX or some other rendering library!

Comment: Yeah that's working much better, now that I know some openGL I'm seeing that I can replace SDL's rendering, and just use it to load .pngs and handle keyboard input

Comment: Actually you could use GLFW! It's like SDL but more minimalistic and faster it handels keyboard input, windowing and other stuff!